# how to control water temperature?

Tags: temperature-control

I need a method to maintain the temperature of the water specifically at 55 degree and 5 degree into two different containers to conduct a thermal cycling. I am keen to address the effect of temperature change (Aging) on a specific material.

Comment: Centigrade or Fahrenheit? What's your local ambient temp? Is this a fermentation?

Answer (score 1):

Sous vide cooking is probably what you're looking for.  There several different methods available, from "rolling your own" with a microcontroller, thermocouple, and heating element (note: you should really only do this if you know what you're doing with electroncs, due to dealing with line voltages for the heater); to using [cheap thermocontrollers](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0088OTON4) with some slow cookers; to using [immersion heaters/circulators](http://www.amazon.com/s?ie=UTF8&field-keywords=sous%20vide%20immersion%20circulator&index=blended) in whatever vessels you choose.

Answer (score -3):

I use a Picobrew Zymatic for that.  www.picobrew.com

Comment: Is this not a water temp control method?